# Checking day against date in Rails 3 using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, validation, simple-form

What's the best way to check the date against a day in Rails?

I have a register where certain registers take place on certain days, and what I want to do is  to restrict the selectable dates to match the days i.e. if the register is set for Monday 15:00, then the date selection should only provide dates which are Monday i.e. 1st April 2013, 8th April 2013, 15th April 2013 etc.

Here is a screenshot of what my current register looks like:

[image]

My form uses the `simple_form` gem, and has the following simple input:

```
<%= f.input :date %>
```

EDIT:
Here is my model, as requested by cthulhu

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_registers
  has_many :students, :through => :student_registers
  belongs_to :event
  attr_accessible :date, :student_ids, :module_class_id, :event_id
end
```

Comment: Do you want to limit the dropdowns to show only some dates (e.g. only mondays), or do you want to validate if a date is a certains day of week ?

Comment: Either would be fine, which one would be easier to implement? I guess the validation one would be easier, right?

Comment: Probably yes, but definitely less user friendly

Comment: Ok, any chance of writing up some code i.e. validation methods on how to implement that?

Comment: Yes, but validation is implemented at model level, so you should attach some code from your models

Comment: One more thing - you say "to match the days i.e. if the register is set for Monday 15:00" , how can I access this data ?

Comment: You have access to the `Event` model, which stores the `day` attribute i.e. Monday - Friday. So the `Register` model has to check if the selected date is equal to the week day itself

Answer (score 2):

Date class has plenty of useful methods, like

```
>> d = Date.today
=> Fri, 05 Apr 2013
>> d.monday?
=> false
>> d.friday?
=> true
>> d.wday
=> 5
```

It should be enough to write a validation method:

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_each :date do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add(attr, "Must be #{event.day}") unless value.wday == Date.parse(event.day).wday # I assume 'event.day' holds a weekday as a String, e.g. 'Monday'
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes I know that already, but I'm looking for a way to validate it in my form, using any of these useful date/time methods

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem :) Do you have problems writing a validation method ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need help with

Answer (score 0):

Are the possible dates stored in a database table? If so, what about doing a collection select which allows you to filter out the values you want. Something like:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:date, Dates.all.where(:day => 5), :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select') %>
```

Replace "Dates.all.where(:day => 5)" with whatever group of dates you have and whatever conditionality you want.

Comment: No, the dates are just displayed using the `<%= f.input :date %>` method